# Tailwind, how to build css file with all supported classes

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using dynamicaly generated classnames in React/Tailwind. I know that it doesn't supported. So I need to generate a css file including all Tailwind functionality. How can I achive it?

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to refactor the code so you support the "tailwind way" because loading the entire library will possibly hurt your performance ,if you are not going to do that you can add all the classes you do not want purged to the safelist in your tailwind.config.js

Here is a link to official doc
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#safelisting-classes

Comment: Wonder how i have skipped it, thanks a lot!
100000+ lines of css is not the best solution